# addEventListener with requestAnimationFrame

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener, requestanimationframe, game-loop

I'm using `window.requestAnimationFrame` to create a game loop.

Everything works great, but when I try to add an event listener it fires hundreds of times really fast.

I've tried using a closure, but that doesn't seem to work.

```
game.update = function(){
   //code that runs every frame
   window.addEventListener('keydown', function(){
      console.log("message");
   },false);
}
```

I want to call a function **ONCE** on the keydown event not multiple times.

Comment: *"I want to call a function ONCE on the keydown event not multiple times."* Then you have to unbind the function after it is called. Why you are binding the event handler inside the loop anyway? Why not outside? Do you want the handler to run once per frame? Please explain better which problem you are trying to solve with that.

Comment: You need to add event listeners once, and not inside your update loop. Your update loop should only add event listeners to objects it creates when it creates them.

Comment: Just don't run that code inside a function that's run every frame

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Event listener is only added if a *new* listener is added. Adding the *same* listener more than once has *no effect* [by design](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener#Multiple_identical_event_listeners).

Move your listener function *out* of the function you’re assigning to `game.update` so that a new copy of listener wouldn’t be created each time you call `addEventListener()`:

```js
var updateListener = function() {
    console.log('message');
};

game.update = function() {
    //code that runs every frame
    window.addEventListener('keydown', updateListener, false);
};
```

Comment: Ok that worked. It just made since to throw it in the loop for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe A bit late, but this doesnt quite make sense to me.  The listener should not be added inside the RAF.  If you put it outside, and assign the handler's result to a variable, then have the RAF get the result and clear the variable, you will have both faster and more stable/predictable performance.  This becomes really obvious for similar tasks, such as using device orientation listeners for controller input on mobile. Events dont need to be looped.  Set it once, it'll fire once every time a key is downed.  The RAF should only be used to update graphics.  Any other logic should be outside it.  For example, movement and game mechanics should bein a setInterval pointing their results to variables and objects outside but accessible to the RAF.  The RAF should only pick up the new position values and set the transforms.  Then it'll run more smoothly, and 'time' will not speed up or slow down, and be consistent on different devices, regardless of frame-rate.